# How to get time difference according to each empid and get the exists total of 50

Tags: mysql

I got:

id empid Ftime  Stime this is the field.

```
 1 01 2017-03-04 07:00:00       2017-03-04 23:45:00 
 2 01 2017-03-05 05:14:12       2017-03-05 21:49:03 
 3 01 2017-03-06 06:08:16       2017-03-06 22:58:13
 4 01 2017-03-07 04:12:19       2017-03-07 23:35:20 
 5 01 2017-03-08 06:17:17       2017-03-08 23:48:19
 6 02 2017-03-04 06:40:11       2017-03-04 22:45:00 
 7 02 2017-03-05 05:19:23       2017-03-05 22:49:03 
 8 02 2017-03-06 07:08:58       2017-03-06 23:58:13
 9 02 2017-03-07 03:12:19       2017-03-07 22:35:20 
10 02 2017-03-08 07:19:12      2017-03-08 23:48:19
```

if total = 54 hours then i need the 4 for empid 01 and so on;

The result i need is like

```
empid total hours
01     10
02     20
```

something like that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't follow your logic by which you arrive at 10 hours for `01` and 20 hours for `02`.

Comment: yeah its just an example result not from the given above.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this i include the minute:

```
select empid,sum(hours)-50,(sum(mins)/60 + sum(sec)/60) mins from
(select empid, TIMEDIFF(stime,ftime),
SUBSTRING(TIMEDIFF(stime,ftime) FROM 1 FOR 2) as hours,
SUBSTRING(TIMEDIFF(stime,ftime) FROM 4 FOR 2) as mins,
SUBSTRING(TIMEDIFF(stime,ftime) FROM 7 FOR 2) as sec
 from yourtable) as a group by empid
```